# can I set an alternative teaser image for a YouTube video

Tags: html, video, youtube

Sometimes I still visit w3schools.org to check HTML5 or other web design technologies when I need to verify correct coding. I'm not seeing a way to set an alternative image when trying to embed a video. I checked both the video element (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and the YouTube blurb (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp).

Does anyone know if a future provision could be in the works?

My workaround is to link my preferred screenshot to the YouTube URL. I data mined YouTube for the Christian music videos I want to promote and I set featured videos on my website: BibleBrowse.org. I have annual JavaScript arrays of the video URL, my teaser image filenames and a text description of the video. With help on an earlier question, I let the getMonth() select the correct monthly video to automate the process.

It would be nice to simply use the HTML5 video method, but it's good to have challenges that I can solve in the meantime.

Comment: To minimize load times, I don't embed the featured video on the home page. Once I figure it out, I plan to launch the YouTube URL in another browser tab and have another link that leads to my multimedia pages. Currently, I'm working on what I call ImageVu which essentially acts as an image portal for all the images on my site. For now, I've almost got the annual featured video screenshots done. I plan on revamping the Christian movies page using another "instance" of ImageVu. ImageVu is basically a web form that dynamically changes the images from a linked pull-down.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [poster](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp) tag

It works something like the below;

```
<video controls="controls" poster="image_url_to_show_while_video_loads">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <img src="img_url_to_show_if_browser_does_not_support_html5" title="Your browser does not support the video tag" />
</video>
```

Comment: I'll probably try it out on my multimedia page so there's no way it can slow down my home page load time.

Comment: I might tweak this later. Considering I have the monthly videos set predetermined in JavaScript arrays, the HTML5 code would need adapted to the video form. I'll have to set ids to get the JavaScript to change/set the variables to the embedded video (the YouTube link and the teaser image/poster). I would simply omit the source line since the video would be displayed embedded.